# Can you help me solve this resolution problem？ ubuntu1804 with sole GPU RTX2080super

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution, cuda

My ubuntu1804 had always had a resolution of 1920x1080 before. After a certain restart, the resolution automatically changed to 640*480, and it could not be changed in the settings. The setting wrote [unknow display] and the resolution column, There is no option to choose
If you enter xrandr -s 1920 x 1080 in the terminal
Will report an error [size 1920 x1080 not found in available modes]

Additional clues:

1. My computer is ubuntu1804, and there is only one  graphics card RTX2080supper
2. After restarting this time, my wireless network card cannot be used, and I need to reinstall the network card driver. This situation of wireless network card usually occurs after ubuntu automatic update, but after  automatically updated in the before,  the resolution was fine, but this time something happened.
3. My graphics card driver is installed in [software and update], and the graphics card version is [nvidia-driver-435]
4. Do I need to reinstall the graphics card driver, mainly because I am afraid of reinstalling the system and the cuda installation is also very troublesome, so I dare not move the graphics card driver